# Android Refresh ListView by ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

in simple ListView in my application i want to add items end of list when scrolling down is finished and refresh that. my code only work to pass data into ListView and it does not working to add to end of list and refresh that. please help me to resolve this problem. Thanks.

```
private ItemAdapter adapter;

public class ReceivedFragment extends ListFragment implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        items = new ArrayList<Item>();

        for ( int i=0; i<=10; i++){
             String a = String.format("title %s", i);
             String b = String.format("description %s", i);
             Item item = new Item(a , b , String.valueOf(i) );
             items.add(item);
        }
        adapter = new ItemAdapter(getActivity(), items);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
     if (prevVisibleItem != firstVisibleItem) {
        if ((firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount) == totalItemCount) {

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.please_wait_to_response_from_server, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Thread thread = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            for (int i = (int) getLastID(); i <= getLastID() + 10; i++) {
                                String a = String.format("title %s", i);
                                String b = String.format("description %s", i);
                                Item item = new Item(a, b, String.valueOf(i));
                                items.add(item);
                            }
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
        }
    }
}

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long thisID) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, thisID);
    }
    public long getLastID() {
        return Long.parseLong(items.get(items.size() - 1).getmLastID());
    }
}
```

ArrayAdapter:

```
public class ItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

    public ItemAdapter(Context c, List<Item> items) {
        super(c,0,items);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ItemView itemView = (ItemView)convertView;
        if (null == itemView)
            itemView = ItemView.inflate(parent);

        itemView.setItem(getItem(position));

        itemView.setBackgroundColor(((position % 2)!=0) ? Color.rgb(229, 229, 229) : Color.WHITE);
        return itemView;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    ArrayAdapter adapter = (ArrayAdapter)yourListView.getAdapter();

  ArrayList<Item>  items = new ArrayList<Item>();
                 for ( int i= (int) getLastID(); i<= getLastID() + 10; i++){

            String a = String.format("title %s", i);
            String b = String.format("description %s", i);

                    Item item = new Item(a , b , String.valueOf(i) );
                    items.add(item);

                }
        adapter.addAll(items);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: if your method is being called at the end of list try this code inside your if condition inside onScroll

Comment: i supposed he would load data from async task that's why i had added the uithread code. thank you mmlooloo i just edited the code

Comment: @mmlooloo post Updated. my problem is not `runOnUiThread` my code without that does not work correctly to add and refresh `ListView`

Comment: @andbee you are still missing this part :adapter.addAll(items); and mmlooloo is right we don't need runOnUiThread here

Comment: @NavinRaj Pandey this is simple and i need to use that. after remove and move line in out of `Thread` my problem is not resolved. i tested that

Comment: if you want to use new thread then you may need but still need to get adapter of list and need to add all new data in it and then notify for data set change

Answer (score -1):

To load your `ListView` with new rows, you should call to `setAdapter` after your list changes.

Instead of :

```
new ItemAdapter(getActivity(), items).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I would try

```
my_listview.setAdapter(new ItemAdapter(getActivity(), items); //items must contains the old and the new items
```

Or just

```
setAdapter(new ItemAdapter(getActivity(), items);
```

As you are using a ListFragment. It is possible that you may need also to call `notifyDataSetChanged()`, but I am not completely sure

Comment: there is no need to create new adapter, every time, waste memory and run GC again and again.